# Conditions for $A^2x=\lambda^2 x \implies Ax=\lambda x$ w/ $A$ hermitian (Hilbert space $L^2$)

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, eigenfunctions

I have found that the function
$$f(z)=e^{iqz}-\frac{a}{2iq+a}e^{iq|z|}$$
satisfies
$$-\partial_z^2f(z)=(q^2+a\delta(z))f(z).$$
Note this looks like an eigenvalue equation, but I am not sure if we can label it as one since $q^2+a\delta(z)$ is not constant (?), i.e., it does not belong to a field $\mathbb{K}$.
Moreover, $f(z)$ is NOT an eigenfunction of $-i\partial_z$:
$$-i\partial_z f(z)=qe^{iqz}-qsgn(z)\frac{a}{2iq+a}e^{iq|z|}=q\left(e^{iqz}-sgn(z)\frac{a}{2iq+a}e^{iq|z|}\right).$$

Is there any condition under which the eigenvectors of an operator, say $A^2$, are also eigenvectors of $A$, where $A$ is hermitian? For example, what happens if I try to define the operator
$$D_z=\sqrt{\partial_z^2+a\delta(z)}?$$
Note that
$$(-iD_z)^2 f(z)=-D_z^2 f(z)=-(\partial_z^2+a\delta(z))f(z)=q^2f(z),$$
which IS an eigenvalue equation. Let me rephrase my question: is there any circumstance under which we can assure $-iD_z f(z)=\pm q f(z)$ given $(-iD_z)^2 f(z)=q^2f(z)$? Can I even define $D_z$?!

I look for an answer in the scope of a vector space of square integrable functions. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that in finite-dimensional spaces, we can asure that
$$A^2x=\lambda^2x\implies Ax=\lambda x,$$
for $A$ hermitian via the spectral theorem. (Obviously the converse is true.) Since this theorem is also true on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, would it be the path to proving what I intend to?

Sorry if I have any misconceptions, and thank you for the insight!

Comment: Let $A:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A^2=0$ and any $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$. So your last equation is not true even in finite dimension.

Comment: @Nicolas $A$ is hermitian

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot that when typed the comment!

Comment: @dn Basically the only thing that can go wrong is that $A$ might have a pair of eigenvalues of the form $\pm \lambda$ with $\lambda \neq 0$. Otherwise, this should work.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think I see what you mean. If eigenvalues are of the form $\pm \lambda$ then, since $Ax_1=\lambda x_1$ and $Ax_2=-\lambda x_2$, we get $A^2x=\lambda^2 x$ for any linear combination $x=a_1x_1+a_2x_2$, and thus we cannot conclude $A^2x=\lambda^2 x\implies Ax=\lambda x$. This is the case, actually. Thank you for the contribution.